# Help me to determine a document class

Tags: document-classes

Could you recognize the document class used [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2010/readings/MIT6_042JS10_chap01.pdf)?

It's quite common, but I didn't find it in document class galleries (maybe I don't know good ones).

Comment: That's the standard `book` class, with the Palatino font, but with the default Computer Modern as the maths font.

Comment: @ChrisS Thanks for a quick answer. Is there a ready-made preambule code to setup the document like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document class is the standard `book` class; the font is Palatino, but with Computer Modern as the maths font.

The document preamble for this would be

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

More information on the TeX Gyre Pagella fonts is available [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgpagella/).

If you'd like to have maths in Palatino as well, you can use

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

More information on the Palatino fonts via the `mathpazo` package is available [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/palatino/).

Comment: I would `\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}`; math is supposed to look better this way.

Comment: Is it possible to set up Palatino for Cyrillic letters as well? I have the "Corrupted NFSS tables" error.